# python click framework - custom multi command implementation in oop's method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I have written some scripts that I'm trying to integrate with click. All the scripts are written in python OOP's.

The issue is that i am trying to build command section in oop's way but couldn't do it properly.

let me show you, what i am trying to do and please note that i am sharing here dummy code it is very similar to the real code.

First thing the directory structure:

```
-customcmd <dir>
|
|->commands <dir>
|  -> abc-command.py
|  -> __init__.py
|
|->__init__.py
|->main.py
|->setup.py
```

1) I have created one file called main.py, which contains following code:

```
import click
import os

plugin_folder = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'commands')

class MyCLI(click.MultiCommand):

    def list_commands(self, ctx):
        rv = []
        for filename in os.listdir(plugin_folder):
            if filename.startswith('__'):
                continue
            if filename.endswith('.py'):
                rv.append(filename[:-3])
        rv.sort()
        return rv

    def get_command(self, ctx, name):
        ns = {}
        fn = os.path.join(plugin_folder, name + '.py')
        with open(fn) as f:
            code = compile(f.read(), fn, 'exec')
            eval(code, ns, ns)
        return ns['cli']

cli = MyCLI()#help='This tool\'s subcommands are loaded from a ''plugin folder dynamically.'
if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

2) abc-command.py

```
@click.command()
@click.option("--file-loc", '-fl', type=open, required=True, default=None, help="Path to the file")

def cli(file_loc):
    """ 
        This is test command

    """
    print("Path to file {}".format(file_loc))
```

- Output of above code when you call main.py:

```
(automation) K:\Pythonenv\automation\customcmd>python main.py
Usage: main.py [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  policyresult  This is test command
```

- Output of above code when you call sub command:

```
(automation) K:\Pythonenv\automation\customcmd>python main.py policyresult --help
Usage: main.py policyresult [OPTIONS]

  This is test command

Options:
  -fl, --file-loc OPEN    Path to the file  [required]
  --help                  Show this message and exit.
```

3) This is how I converted the procedural code of abc-command.py code:

```
  class policyresult():



    def __init__(self):
        pass


    @click.command()
    @click.option("--file-loc", '-fl', type=open, required=True, default=None, help="Path to the file")

    def cli(self,file_loc):
        """ 
            This is test command

        """
        print("Path to file {}".format(file_loc))



obj = policyresult()
obj.cli()
```

- Output of above code doesn't match with the previous output when the code was procedural in abc-command.py:

Here i am calling the main.py

```
(automation) K:\Pythonenv\automation\customcmd>python main.py
Usage: main.py [OPTIONS]
Try "main.py --help" for help.

Error: Missing option "--file-loc" / "-fl".
```

In the above output you can see it is directly going into the sub-command options things and giving error as well.

As far as i understand list_commands() which is in main.py can't list out the commands, this part i can't understand why it is not working properly.

I tried various things but couldn't find the proper way to implement OOP's in abc-command.py because of that my ouput doesn't match.

I am new to this click framework, please suggest any new changes in my approach if needed.

please look into this, sorry for this weird way to explaining this.

Answer (score -1):

abc-command.py is evaluated before click parses command options because of this line in the file invoking the `cli` method:

```py
obj.cli()
```

Also, in the `get_command` method implemented for the multi-command, commands are supposed to expose a 'cli' name in their namespace.

To fix this error, in `abc-command.py` update the line invoking the cli command with:

```py
cli = obj.cli
```

so that a cli name is exposed in `abc-command.py` module